# XSL Transformation of XML into smaller XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML files to convert into smaller standardized XML Files. For this I'm using VBA and XSLT as the template.

My issue is that I receive an error on the conversion and when using http://xsltransform.net/ I'm not able to catch the error in the XSLT template.

Can someone help me adjusting the XSLT to be able to extract/create a XML with the node "FileVersion"

Below a sample of the XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AuditFile xmlns="urn:UP:Standard" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:UP:Standard C:\Standard.XSD">
<Header>
<FileVersion>1_01</FileVersion>
<CompanyID>507</CompanyID>
<TaxBasis>W239</TaxBasis>
    
</Header>
</AuditFile>
```

The XSL Template used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0" >


  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Header">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="FileVersion"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Header">
    <FileVersion>
      <xsl:value-of select="FileVersion" />
    </FileVersion>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you receive an error then show the exact error message. I get no error running your code - but the result is NOT what you expect, because (1) `Header` is not the root element and (2) the source XML has a default namespace and (3) you don't have a template matching `FileVersion`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your document content is bound to the namespace `urn:UP:Standard`. In order to address them in the XPath in your XSLT, you need to declare that namespace and use the prefix in your XPath. In this solution, I chose the namespace-prefix `UP`, but you can use whatever you would like as long as you are consistent in how you reference it in your XPath in the stylesheet.
- The root element is `/UP:AuditFile`, so the template you have defined matching `/Header` won't match anything. You could either match on `/` or `/UP:AuditFile` or `UP:AuditFile` if you wanted to have a template that matched at the start of the document processing to create the `<root`> element and then generate the `<FileVersion>`.
- From the template matching `UP:AuditFile` you want to apply-templates to it's `UP:Header` child element, which will then match on the template matching `UP:Header`, in which you can construct your own `<FileVersion>` element (without a namespace) and then select the `xsl:value-of` it's child element `UP:FileVersion`
- Since the `urn:UP:Standard` namespace is not used in the output, you can exclude it from the output by adding `exclude-result-prefixes="UP"` to the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Adjustments applied:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0" 
    xmlns:UP="urn:UP:Standard" exclude-result-prefixes="UP">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    
    <xsl:template match="UP:AuditFile">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="UP:Header"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="UP:Header">
        <FileVersion>
            <xsl:value-of select="UP:FileVersion" />
        </FileVersion>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```